# Delphi: How can I scale the main application window while having the SetProcessDPIAware set?

Tags: delphi, dpi

In maintain one *and luckily only one* application in Delphi XE6, sort of a Color Picker, where I create a screenshot of the whole screen as follows:

(**I left there all my comments for you to see my thinking in the past, though now XP and Vista are unsupported by me.**)

```
var
  hDesktopWindow: THandle;
  DesktopCanvas: TCanvas;
  DeskRect, SourceRect: TRect;

begin
  DesktopCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
  try

    hDesktopWindow := GetDesktopWindow;
    DesktopCanvas.Handle := GetDC(hDesktopWindow);
    try

      //  1. On XP/Vista DesktopCanvas.ClipRect doesn't work,
      //     so we have to use Screen.DesktopRect!
      //  2. Don't use Screen.DesktopRect on 7/8, because in higher DPI
      //     it doesn't keep ratio when SetProcessDPIAware isn't called;
      //     it's worse for debugging.
      //  3. Without calling SetProcessDPIAware in DPR, the screenshot
      //     on 7/8 was distorted if DPI was set to 150 / 200%;
      //     worked normally with DPI 125% though.
      //  4. SetProcessDPIAware doesn't work on XP,
      //     fortunately on XP all DPI settings work well without it.

//      if ((Win32MajorVersion = 6) and (Win32MinorVersion >= 1)) or
//         (Win32MajorVersion > 6)
        // 7/8 or higher
//        then SourceRect := DesktopCanvas.ClipRect
        // XP/Vista
//        else

SourceRect := DeskRect;

      ImgSnapshot.Canvas.CopyRect(ImgSnapshot.ClientRect, DesktopCanvas, SourceRect);

    finally
      ReleaseDC(hDesktopWindow, DesktopCanvas.Handle);
    end;

  finally
    DesktopCanvas.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

That code works in all DPI settings while in:

## .dpr

```
SetProcessDPIAware;
```

is set.

If it wasn't for that line of code, that screenshot would scale.

---

## My problem

I don't really know my way through different DPI settings and now when I bought 4K UHD display I get a clear idea on what some users reported:

> The main window is too small to read and click on.

---

I can't get the `SetProcessDPIAware` reverted, I suppose, at runtime, right?

How can I scale the main application window while having the `SetProcessDPIAware` set?

Comment: Set the Scaled property of the main form to True. More fundamentally your post seems to say the following. 1. I understand that my application has issues with high DPI. 2. I know that my appreciation of high DPI is lacking. 3. I want to address 1 but lot address 2. I see this a lot on this site and I find it depressing. Address item 2 first. Then you will have the knowledge to deal with 1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, will try my best.